# First letter is always black when printing with MDL from Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, printing, colors

I have tables in which I want to represent negative numbers as red text. The problem is that in the print preview the color is not applied to the first letter.

[image]

I have CSS rules in a media print block. I have tried to put the number in a span and applied the redText class to both the span and the td itself. I have tried to apply the color to the class element and every subsequent element.

```
@media print {
  .redText, .redText * {
    color: #f44336 !important;
  }
}
```

The html is:

```
<td class="textRight band0Bchange_ue_04 redText">
  <span class="redText">-1,566</span>
</td>
```

This is the HTML in the regular view where the color is rendered correctly. I am not sure whether is possible to inspect the elements in the print preview.

Edit: The issue is caused by the Material Design library. I have put the relevant html and css into a jsFiddle. This works well. Once I add material.min.css the print breaks with the behaviour as described above.

https://jsfiddle.net/goldrydigital/8fzby8aq/2/

I have added a print preview on the jsfiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/goldrydigital/8fzby8aq/6/

Here the problem doesn't display. The problem is only visible when I use the actual print function on Firefox.

[image]

Comment: Please show your HTML also.

Comment: share you code or post working example

Comment: It's Working Fine https://jsfiddle.net/AhirHasmukh/8fzby8aq/1/. I have tried to do print.

Comment: I updated the jsfiddle to show the problem. Sorry for the delay. The issue is caused by the mdl css library. https://jsfiddle.net/goldrydigital/8fzby8aq/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check, may be possible you have written first letter CSS for print or main style sheet.

```
.redText::first-letter {
    color: #000000;
}
```

I tried in codepen also it is working fine as you provided the code in question section.

Comment: I have created a jsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/goldrydigital/8fzby8aq/2/ The behaviour is caused by the mdl css library in project. Can you check again please? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I get the right result by implicitly setting color: #f44336 on the first letter. Very strange. I did not define the first letter to be black anywhere. In fact, I did not even know about the first-letter selector until just now.

Answer (score 1):

Santosh provides a good answer which helped me to solve this issue. Here just to confirm the bit in the mdl css library which causes the issue. Apparently black prints faster this way.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have put your span at wrong location...

In your output -364 do not have any comma or dot still it is leaving the first digit and rest all are red colored.

I suggest you, check the HTML tags.

Comment: I have created a jsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/goldrydigital/8fzby8aq/2/ The behaviour is caused by the mdl css library in project. Can you check again please? Thanks for your help.